# Add Unity UI Scripts to GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, inspector

I'm using new Unity 5.02, and some objects work as a button via script. And when I add the Button through the canvas, there's ButtonScript (Unity), TextScript (Unity) And when I want to add these scripts into other GameObjects, the Unity does not show them to me.  But I when I download another older project,  there I could add UI scripts, anywhere!

What is the reason? And how can I get these scripts in the free use of the project?

Comment: you can use UI scripts only on objects that are inside your Canvas (the Canvas game object must be their root parent)

Comment: I can not manually add UIscript even Canvas!

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean... you can add a GameObject to your scene in the hierarchy view... if you want to add UI scripts, you must add them to objects that are under the Canvas object (not on the Canvas, but as children). You can do this manually in the editor or you can do this dynamically from the C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all scripts, the unit requires an additional download different packages. Even if the elements are present in the standard elements, they can be used only with the presence of the corresponding package.